# SBT jsDependency file name trouble

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, webjars

I'm trying to add a jsDependency to build.sbt file of my project, like it's declared on webjars:

```
"org.webjars" % "jsplumb" % "2.0.7"
```

However, I can't figure out where am I supposed to find a filename which should be added after it and a /. I tried to write:

```
"org.webjars" % "jsplumb" % "2.0.7" / "jsplumb.js"
```

But that didn't work. All the other sensible options I managed to come up with, like:

```
"org.webjars" % "jsplumb" % "2.0.7" / "plumb.js"
```

didn't work either. I think I might be doing something terribly wrong, but where am I supposed to find that name/path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [webjars.org](http://www.webjars.org/), find your library `jsplumb`, click on the Files link in the right-most column. There you can see the files contained in that jar, and figure out which one you want. In this case, I suppose it is `jsPlumb-2.0.7.js`.